# HTML change the line of the checkbox automatically

Tags: javascript, html, css, checkbox, flexbox

This is how the website look.[image]

In the first line of the checkbox, the last checkbox and its label isn't connected together, how am I going to put the checkbox and its label in the same line.

This is the css of the checkbox

```
.checkboxContainer {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 80px;
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    padding-inline: 50px;
}

.checkboxContainer label {
    font-size: 25px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

The way I created the checkbox (I have shortened the data)

```
const checkboxContainer=document.querySelector(".checkboxContainer");

let nutritions=[{"id":1,"label":"食品分類"},...];
for (let tmp of nutritions) {
    const checkboxId="checkbox"+tmp.id;
    const checkbox='<input type="checkbox" id="'+checkboxId+'" class="checkbox-input">';
    const label='<label for"'+checkboxId+'">'+tmp.label+'</label>';
    checkboxContainer.innerHTML+=checkbox+label;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve the problem and also simplify your code by restructuring the html.

[Label elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) may contain an input element.

So this original markup:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-1">
<label for="checkbox-1"> Text</label>
```

May be simplifed to:

```
<label><input type="checkbox">Text</label>
```

And this groups the checkbox and label, making the `for` and `id` attributes unnecessary. Then by applying css [white-space: nowrap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) to the labels the problem is solved.

**Snippet**

*The JavaScript is omitted since it's irrelevant to the solution.*

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
h5 {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  color: blue;
}

.checkboxContainer {
  width: 16rem;
  border-right: 2px dotted red;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.checkboxContainer label {
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<h5>Modified</h5>
<div class="checkboxContainer">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox">1-label
  </label>
  <label>
  <input type="checkbox">2-label
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox">3-label
  </label>
  <label>
  <input type="checkbox">4-label
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox">5-label
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox">6-VeryLongLabelNameToTestHowItWrapsText
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox">7-label
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox">8-label
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox">9-label
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox">10-label
  </label>
</div>

<h5>Original</h5>
<div class="checkboxContainer">
  <input type="checkbox" id="c1">
  <label for="c1">1-label</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="c2">
  <label for="c2">2-label</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="c3">
  <label for="c3">3-label</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="c4">
  <label for="c4">4-label</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="c5">
  <label for="c5">5-label</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="c6">
  <label for="c6">6-VeryLongLabelNameToTestHowItWrapsText</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="c7">
  <label for="c7">7-label</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="c8">
  <label for="c8">8-label</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="c9">
  <label for="c9">9-label</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="c10">
  <label for="c10">10-label</label>
</div>
```

Comment: After using the code, the checkboxes changed line automatically, but later I accessed the website using my phone, the checkboxes got in a line instead of displaying the way I see on the computer. Do you know how to fix this problem?

Comment: @henryChan - I think there is a problem with the media query in your new version. I'll update you if I find the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap the checkbox and the label to the same element, then make that wrapper have `display: inline-block` property:

```js
const checkboxContainer = document.querySelector(".checkboxContainer");

let nutritions = [{
  "id": 1,
  "label": "食品分類"
}, {
  "id": 1,
  "label": "食品分類類分"
}, {
  "id": 1,
  "label": "食品分類分"
}, {
  "id": 1,
  "label": "食品分類分"
}, {
  "id": 1,
  "label": "食品分類品品類"
}, {
  "id": 1,
  "label": "食品"
}, {
  "id": 1,
  "label": "食品分類食分"
}, {
  "id": 1,
  "label": "食品分類"
}, {
  "id": 1,
  "label": "食類分類"
}, {
  "id": 1,
  "label": "食品分類類類類類分"
}, {
  "id": 1,
  "label": "食品分類"
}, {
  "id": 1,
  "label": "食品分類"
}, {
  "id": 1,
  "label": "食品分類"
}, {
  "id": 1,
  "label": "食品分類"
}, {
  "id": 1,
  "label": "食品分類"
}, {
  "id": 1,
  "label": "食品分類"
}, {
  "id": 1,
  "label": "食品分類"
}, {
  "id": 1,
  "label": "食品分類"
}, {
  "id": 1,
  "label": "食品分類"
}, {
  "id": 1,
  "label": "食品分類"
}, {
  "id": 1,
  "label": "食品分類"
}, {
  "id": 1,
  "label": "食品分類"
}, {
  "id": 1,
  "label": "食品分類"
}, {
  "id": 1,
  "label": "食品分類"
}, {
  "id": 1,
  "label": "食品分類"
}, ];
for (let tmp of nutritions) {
  const checkboxId = "checkbox" + tmp.id;
  const checkbox = '<input type="checkbox" id="' + checkboxId + '" class="checkbox-input">';
  const label = '<label for"' + checkboxId + '">' + tmp.label + '</label>';
  checkboxContainer.innerHTML += `<div>${checkbox + label}</div>`;
}
```

```css
.checkboxContainer {
  display: block;
  padding-top: 80px;
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-inline: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

.checkboxContainer div {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.checkboxContainer label {
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="checkboxContainer">
</div>
```